# React: How to run some async walk functions synchronously?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise

I'm new to react and I have learnt about Promise / `async` / `await`. I know how to use them in many cases but I got very confused on how to run this code:

```
    const file_paths = [];

    var walker = walk.walk(unzip_base+zipfilename, { followLinks: false });

    console.log('check 1')

    walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
        const folder_path = root.split('/');
        const folder = folder_path[folder_path.length-1]; 
        file_paths.push('/john/server/data/'+folder + '/' + stat.name);
        next();
    });

    walker.on('end', function() {
      console.log('walker end');
    });

    console.log('check 2')

    console.log('file_paths: ', file_paths)
```

The function `walker.on('file' ... )` simply recursively iterates all files in the provided directory, take the file's path and append it in the `file_paths` list. I don't know how it is implemented, but it runs asynchronously.

The console output is now:

```
check 1
check 2
file_paths: []
walker end
```

I can confirm that `file_paths` is definitely not empty after a few seconds.
How can I convert this code such that it waits until `walk end` before executing `console.log('file_paths: ', file_paths)`, such that `file_paths` will be loaded by the time it prints `check 2` ?

Comment: What does `walk.walk` return, an object with a custom callback method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot hope to somehow get a synchronous flow of what runs asynchronously.

You can however, make use of `async` `await` to make it easier to organise your code:

```
async function collectPaths(unzip_base, zipfilename) {
    const file_paths = [];

    var walker = walk.walk(unzip_base+zipfilename, { followLinks: false });

    console.log('check 1');

    walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
        const folder_path = root.split('/');
        const folder = folder_path[folder_path.length-1]; 
        file_paths.push('/john/server/data/'+folder + '/' + stat.name);
        next();
    });

    await new Promise(resolve => 
        walker.on('end', function() {
            console.log('walker end');
            resolve();
        })
    );

    console.log('check 2');

    console.log('file_paths: ', file_paths);

    return file_paths; // might be of interest to the caller
}
```

But be aware that the *caller* of `collectPaths` will still be faced with the asynchronous behaviour: the call of `collectPaths` will return immediately, returning a promise object, and the caller is responsible to *also* apply the asynchronous pattern and *await* that promise to be resolved. This it can do with either chaining a `.then` call, or by using itself the `async` `await` syntax.

At no point can you write a function that will only return when the job is done. `async` `await` syntax can make it a bit easier to deal with asynchronous code, but it remains asynchronous.

Comment: Bravo!! I didn't realize I should wrap the `walker.on('end'...)` call with `Promise()`. I was doing something more complicated and messy.